# ViewDidAppear called repeatedly when presenting a SecondViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I'm working on a exercise to present a SecondViewController in ViewController.

This is how i called the view Controller.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"View Did Appear" );

    SecondViewController* secViewCtrl = [ [ SecondViewController alloc ] init ];

    [ self presentViewController:secViewCtrl animated:NO completion:nil ];

}
```

When i run the code. The secondViewController keep presenting. When i call this from ViewDidLoad i get bad access. How can i fix this problem.?

Ex:

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"View Did Appear" );

    SecondViewController* secViewCtrl = [ [ SecondViewController alloc ] init ];

    [ self presentViewController:secViewCtrl animated:NO completion:nil ];

}
```

SecondViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [ self.view setBackgroundColor:[ UIColor colorWithRed:64.0/255.0 green:106.0/255.0 blue:128.0/255.0 alpha:1.0 ] ];

    UIButton* backBtn = [ [ UIButton alloc ] init ];

    [ backBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 44) ];

    [ backBtn setImage:[ UIImage imageNamed:@"Circle.png" ] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];

    [ backBtn setBackgroundColor:[ UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.2 ] ];

    [ self.view addSubview:backBtn ];

}
```

I can see the color code of SecondViewController. But when i log ViewDidLoad in ViewController. Its keep repeating. This makes me not to use any button action.

Comment: Are you calling this code from `SecondViewController.m` (or one of its subclass) ?

Comment: Am calling SecondViewController.m from ViewController.m

Comment: Can you show `viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear/viewDidload` of both of the view controllers ?

Comment: start by calling super

Comment: I've edited the code of how i have done

Comment: use  BOOL value to set the view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing what is happening I would say that `SecondViewController` is a subclass of `ViewController`.

Then when `SecondViewController` appears it'll call again its super class's appearing methods and that'll result in this infinite loop.

If that's the case, simply set `SecondViewController` as an `UIViewController` subclass instead of `ViewController`

Comment: This solution worked for me. I changed ViewController to UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

try putting this code in a method and call the method from viewDidAppear: with performSelectorOnMainThread:

Comment: Its still the same.
This is how I did
    [ self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(callSecondViewController withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES ];

Comment: ok add 
[super viewDidAppear:animated] in viewDidAppear of viewController